# crear funcion integrada que me el valor de una columna

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando crear una funcion integrada en mysql para que me devuelva el valor sueldo (columna sueldo) cuando ingreso un id_Empleado (columna id_empleado). Las dos columnas se encuentran en la tabla empleados.

````
CREATE FUNCTION FN_SUELDO_EMPLEADO (Id_empleado int)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SET @SUELDO = 0;
SELECT NOMBRE, SUELDO FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE ID_EMPLEADO = ID_EMPLEADO INTO @SUELDO;
return @SUELDO;
END //
DELIMITER ; ```
````

Comment: Estas tratando de asignar el valor NOMBRE y SUELDO a la variable @SUELDO. Solo borra la columna NOMBRE del SELECT y deberia de funcionar.

Comment: si muchas gracias!